# Android background applied to all elements

Tags: android, background, dialog

I have a custom dialog with the following theme applied

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="highscoreStyle" parent="@android:Theme.Dialog"> 
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/highscoreshape</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    </style>
```

and inside my highscoreshape.xml I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#ffffff" android:endColor="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

This works just fine and provides me with a white dialog with rounded corners. My only issue is all the elements inside my dialog gets the same background the dialog has. So if I add a textview the textview will get a white background with rounded corners too. Is there a way to apply this style to the main LinearLayout of the dialog and not everything inside the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, instead of doing it as an item inside my theme I applied it to the main linearlayout's background and now everything looks good.

Comment: I have your problem and unfortunately got to this solution too :(